# How to calculate a position offset based on an object's rotation, openGL, C++

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I'm trying to calculate a position offset for my camera based on the rotation of an object in the scene, to give the illusion that the camera is fixed "behind" the object. I can get the camera and object to turn simultaneously, but the camera is not fixed behind the object.

[image]

The camera moves based on the objects position, but as the object is rotating, the object's position is never changed, which means both the object and camera are stationary. I need to take the rotation into account because as you can see from the media, after some turning, the object is no longer in view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that feels like an order of multiplication problem. you need to rotate first, and then apply the offset, not the other way around.

Comment: yeah I understand but there is no offset at the moment. My question is how would I calculate it?

Comment: You can always do the good old "lookat the car" like this
http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18933/camera-movement-along-with-model 
but instead of using a fixed camera position for your camera xyz, use positionOfTheCar.xyz  -offsetScalar * directionOfTheCarUnitVector.xyz, speaking abstractly, of course

Comment: That's what I'm using at the moment, however that doesn't give me the offset so I can move my camera behind the car based on the car's rotation